# MISRA 2008 C++ warning for getline

Tags: c++

here is the code below,

```
while (getline(in, line)) {
    ..
  }
```

warning is: "Implicit conversion from struct to bool"

how shall i handle the return value from getline to eliminate the warning

Comment: @dan: The message is from the `getline(...)` returning a stream object, and this is seen as "bad", apparently.

Comment: Maybe be explicit about it? `while(static_cast<bool>(getline(in, s))`

Comment: @mats if my understanding is correct while(!getline(in, line).fail()) the check will pass if there is not failure right, and while can continue..

Comment: Yes, that was my intention. Of course, `static_cast<bool>` will likely work too.

Comment: @Mats, what if EOF has been reached will fail() also take that into account?

Comment: In other words, I'm reflecting the `operator bool` as per C++11. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/

Comment: Yes, EOF is a "fail" (or "bad", can't quite remember which one it is).

Comment: @allthanks for the help, also i think we can use getline(in, line).good(), as good() will be true only if all other conditions(fail, bad, eof) are not present.

Comment: @Mats fail does include bad. but i think it does not consider eof.

Comment: Using `good()` is another solution - didn't think of that. However, if my solution was different, then while `(cin << x) ...` would not work for EOF - and since this is the accepted style for doing this, it should

Answer (score 0):

`while(!getline(in, line).fail())` should avoid the "struct" type error. Although it does look rather awful in my mind, and maybe the right thing is to tell the MISRA tool that "this is not wrong" in some way (I'm not that familiar with MISRA - I have used Coverity, which has an option for marking a supposed defect as "Not a problem", either in the generated report or by adding a special comment in the code).

Comment: How about `!!getline(...`. But this misses `eof()`, which isn't a fail condition. The straightforward `while (getline(...).good())` does check EOF.

Comment: So you are saying that http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/ saying that it's equivalent of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_not/ is not true? And that the common `while (cin << blah)...` needs extra code to catch eof?

Comment: The suggestion to use !! instead of !fail was for mere readability. Neither checks EOF. OTOH, `while(cin<<blah)` checks whether the last extraction succeeded, regardless of it htting EOF. I think MISRA is plain wrong here, any alternative seems inferior.

Comment: Right, I was just coming back after my morning clense before going to work, realising essentially that "we're both right and wrong at the same time", so `while(cin << blah)` is exactly the same check as the original statement in the original code, which will be `false` if `fail()` is returns false. `fail()` doesn't take EOF into account, but it doesn't really have to, since knowing if the last extraction failed due to reading pas EOF or something else is meaningless for purposes other than determining if the entire file was read (or something like invalid input was encountered).